# What is reason behind this question in probability?

Tags: probability

a box contains 5 red and 4 green and 6 black balls. if 3 balls are drawn at random.

i) what is probability that all balls are red color?

ii) what is probability that none ball is red?

ans. of i) is 2/91

ans. of ii) is 24/91

my question is for the answer of second case why can not i deduct 2/91 from 1.

(probability of none ball is red = 1- probability of all ball is red)

why i am not getting my answer from above method?

please explain

thanks

Comment: By deduction 2/91 from 1 you are calculating the probability that **not all balls are red**, not the probability that **all balls are not red**.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that $0,1,2$ or $3$ balls are red. The first question is about the case where all $3$ are red; the second question is about the case where $0$ are red. If you subtract the result of the first question from $1$, you get the probability of the complement of "all 3 are red", which is not "0 are red" but rather "0, 1, or 2 are red". Thus the complement of the first question is not what is asked for in the second question.

Comment: please explain a little more

Answer (score 1):

Probability that all $3$ balls are red:

$$\frac{\binom{\color\red5}{3}}{\binom{\color\red5+\color\green4+\color\black6}{3}}=\frac{2}{91}$$

---

Probability that **not** all $3$ balls are red:

$$1-\frac{\binom{\color\red5}{3}}{\binom{\color\red5+\color\green4+\color\black6}{3}}=\frac{89}{91}$$

---

Probability that all $3$ balls are **not** red:

$$\frac{\binom{\color\green4+\color\black6}{3}}{\binom{\color\red5+\color\green4+\color\black6}{3}}=\frac{24}{91}$$